# Access String array in Json

Tags: json, reactjs

The API I am using has a nested string array it seems, I need to extract the path from it, but I cannot figure out how....

This is a break down of what I need to access.

the productimage is wrapped in quotes...

```
[
 {title: "Item 1",
  productimage: "[{"1":{"size":"75x75","path":"/10000/img.jpg"}]"
 },
 {title: "Item 2",
  productimage: "[{"1":{"size":"75x75","path":"/20000/img.jpg"}]"
 }
]
```

I am trying to access the image path...

The problem seems to be reading the string, I have attempted to treat it like an array, and a string and get mixed results..

Edited:

here is the entire productimages object, it is coming from an apache database that i have no control over.

```
productimages: "[{"1":{"size":"75x75","path":"/100000/101819-75x75-A.jpg"}},{"2":{"size":"222x222","path":"/100000/101819-600x600-A.jpg"}},{"3":{"size":"328x328","path":"/100000/101819-600x600-A.jpg"}}]"
```

my current axios call looks like this.

```
async function handleSubmit(searchData) {
    if (searchData) {
      const payload = searchData;
      try {
        const response = await axios({
          url: `${baseUrl}q=*:*&fq=title:${payload}&fq=storeid:1234
          method: "get",
        });
        //Set Hook
        setData(response.data.response.docs);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      } 
    }
  }
```

Here is the response data that is being set..

```
{productid: 1234, itemups: 1234, title: "productname",  productimages: "[{"1":{"size":"75x75","path":"/100000/101819-75x75-A.jpg"}},{"2":{"size":"222x222","path":"/100000/101819-600x600-A.jpg"}},{"3":{"size":"328x328","path":"/100000/101819-600x600-A.jpg"}}]", productcount: 7}
```

I can get everything out of this, except the image.

Comment: have you tried `JSON.parse(productimage)`? It will be converted to array

Answer (score 2):

You've to parse `productimage`:

```js
const parsedArray = array.map(obj => {
  let path = '';
  try {
    const productimage = JSON.parse(`${obj.productimage}`);
    path = productimage[0].path
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }

  return { ...obj, path  }
});
```

[EDIT]
Axios response:

```js
axios() // some axios call
  .then(res => res.data)
  .then(array => {
    // ... here you can transform your array
  })
```

Comment: So i tried to do this, however, the axios call is pulling ALL the data, and storing it and then setting it in a Hook. Do I need to run this in a separate function?

Comment: I've edited the answer for you. You can chain your axios response and transform your data.

Comment: getting this error.. Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? looks like the response you're getting is not correct json.

Comment: ok, i have edited my original post with the axios call i currently have, plug the hook, and the data being set in the hook.

Comment: Problem is with stringified json, can you wrap it in string literals and retry? I've edited my answer:
`${obj.productimage}`

Comment: humm. I am pretty sure your on the right path, and its the data that is the problem. It gives me an error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, when logging it, the data going in, is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214343/discussion-between-muhammad-ali-and-bnd10706).

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your json is properly formatted.

```
{
 [
  {"title": "Item 1",
   "productimage": "[{"1":{"size":"75x75","path":"/10000/img.jpg"}]"
 ]
}
```